# CFG-Infinite recursion

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, regular-expressions

As you see, the string production process never ends.

Can someone explain me if  this language is  regular or not  ?

$ S \to Α Β S $

$ A \to S  $

$ B \to a B b $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is regular:
$$ L = \{\}$$
It doesn't contain any word not even the empty word $\varepsilon$.
The automaton recognizing it has only one state; a reject state.
Or if you are using DFA the automaton just wouldn't have an accept state.

Notice that the language is regular but that the grammar is written in a form that's usually used for context free grammars, but the language produced by it is still regular.

Comment: I am confused.. 
The reason that it doesnt contain any word is that the string production process is infinite, so it  cannot product a string ?

Comment: @TuMama exactly